# How to mapping type ENUMS in Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, enums, doctrine-orm, mapping

I am using PHP 8.1.6, Symfony 6 with Doctrine ORM. I've been trying to get it to work for a long time but with no luck. I have followed tutorials but they are usually from other older versions of Symfony or Doctrine and those options do not work, I will thank greatly if someone can give me a little example to be able to make it work and understand it better.

Comment: #[Column(type: 'string', enumType: Suit::class)]
public Suit $suit;

Comment: As long as you have Doctrine 2.11: https://www.doctrine-project.org/2022/01/11/orm-2.11.html

Comment: I've written a full blog post on the subject, maybe you will find hints in it: https://www.strangebuzz.com/en/blog/using-php-8-1-enumerations-in-a-symfony-project . Yes be sure, to update Doctrine first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to create your enum,
2. Please create your mapping class in the `type`
   directory:

   ```
   public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
   {
       $enumClass = $this->getEnum();

       return $enumClass::from($value);
   }


   public function convertToDatabaseValue($enum, AbstractPlatform $platform)
   {
       return $enum->value;
   }
   ```
3. Please register in doctrine.yaml in your dbal types

   ```
       types: 
            enumType: App\Doctrine\DBAL\Type\EnumType
   ```
4. In your Entity, you need to put the `enumType` in the `orm` column
   and `enum` in your Entity type